# Getting attribute name of XML node with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to parse an **data.xml** like this:

```
<data>
    <!-- Prices Material -->
    <prM type='prBM'>13.50</prM>
    <prM type='prBP'>12.50</prM>
    <prM type='prBN'>10.50</prM>
</data>
```

I've already achieved to get to values by using this code:

```
var xml = loadXMLDoc("includes/data.xml");    
var prM = xml.getElementsByTagName('prM')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

However, I cannot find the way to obtain the 'type' values, which are: 'prBM','prBP','prBN'. 
I tried with `xml.getElementsByTagName('prM')[0].childNodes[0].nodeName`, as well as any other attributes, but nothing works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) for that

```
var prM = xml.getElementsByTagName('prM')[0].getAttribute('type');
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasted plenty of time trying to get that.